# Búsqueda de substring en un string en una lista

Tags: python, spyder

Me ha surgido una duda respecto a los strings en listas.
Yo tengo una lista que contiene strings:

```
lista = ['Informática', 'Matemáticas', 'Ingles Avanzado', 'Lengua', 'Alemán Avanzado]
```

Y quiero encontrar los elementos de la lista que contiene la palabra `'Avanzado'`.
¿Alguien sabe como podría hacerlo? He probado lo siguiente:

```
def find_str(lista):
    lista_nueva = []
    for i in range(0, len(lista)):
        indice = lista[i].find('Avanzado')
        lista_nueva.append(indice)
    return lista_nueva
```

Pero no me devuelve lo que quiero. Me tendría que devolver `lista_nueva = ['Ingles Avanzado', 'Alemán Avanzado']`. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien método `find` busca si la cadena existe en  un string, esto te regresa el indice de la posicion o `-1` en caso no haya sido encontrado, por lo que la salida de tu codigo seria `[-1, -1, 7, -1, 7]` donde vemos que hay `-1` que indica que no hay coincidencias, solo 2 donde aparece el `7` que es la posición donde aparece la cadena `Avanzado`.

Lo puedes dejar asi pero tendras que hacer algo como esto

```py
def find_str1(lista):
    lista_nueva = []
    for i in range(0, len(lista)):
        indice = lista[i].find('Avanzado')
        #verificamos si existe coincidencia
        if indice != -1:
          #agregamos a la lista
          lista_nueva.append(lista[i])
    return lista_nueva
```

La mejor forma es hacerlo con una compresion de lista como indico @Candid Moe

```py
[x for x in lista if "Avanzado" in x]
```

O Lo puedes hacer de una forma tradicional

```
def find_str(lista):
    lista_nueva = []
    for i in range(0, len(lista)):
        indice = 'Avanzado' in lista[i]
        if indice:
          lista_nueva.append(lista[i])
    return lista_nueva
```

Answer (score 3):

Muy simple:

```
lista = ['Informática', 'Matemáticas', 'Ingles Avanzado', 'Lengua', 'Alemán Avanzado']
lista_nueva = [x for x in lista if "Avanzado" in x]
```

La comprensión de lista se lee asi: generar una lista con los elementos de "lista" que contengan la palabra "Avanzado".

Si sólo quieres saber si una cadena es parte de otra, basta con preguntar `subcadena in cadena`.

Si tienes una compresión de lista simple como `[x for x in lista]`, que incluye todos los elementos, puedes seleccionar los que te interesa agregando un `if` a la cola:

```
[x for x in lista if "Avanzado" in x]
```

Comment: Pensé que sería más complicado, era bastante sencillo. Intente utilizar algo parecido a regex pero no me salía nada. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo también con un if y comprobando la ultima parte del array para ver si es igual a la palabra 'Avanzado' asi:

```
lista = ['Informática', 'Matemáticas', 'Ingles Avanzado', 'Lengua', 'Alemán 
Avanzado']
lista_avanzados=[]

def find_str(lista):
  for i in lista:
    if i [len(i)-8:len(i)] == 'Avanzado':
      lista_avanzados.append(i)
  print(lista_avanzados)

find_str(lista)
```

O incluso si te gusta más puedes usar el comparador 'in' asi:

```
lista = ['Informática', 'Matemáticas', 'Ingles Avanzado', 'Lengua', 
'Alemán Avanzado']
lista_avanzados=[]

def find_str(lista):
  for i in lista:
    if 'Avanzado' in i:
      lista_avanzados.append(i)
  print(lista_avanzados)

find_str(lista)
```

En los dos casos el output es el siguiente:

```
['Ingles Avanzado', 'Alemán Avanzado']
```

Si quisieras borrar el 'Avanzado' de la lista de output lo podrías hacer añadiendo unas lineas de codigo usando el método de cadenas de python ".rstrip" así:

```
lista = ['Informática', 'Matemáticas', 'Ingles Avanzado' ,'Lengua', 
'Alemán Avanzado']
lista_avanzados=[]

def find_str(lista):
  x = ''
  for i in lista:
    if 'Avanzado' in i:
      x = i
      x = x.rstrip('Avanzado')
      lista_avanzados.append(x)
  print(lista_avanzados)

find_str(lista)
```

Comment: Y si quisiera eliminar del output la palabra 'Avanzado'? Es decir que me quedara la  lista `['Ingles', 'Alemán']`, ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Ya lo he añadido en la edición de la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Esta tarea se puede realizar utilizando este método:

```
# Código Python para demostrar
# para encontrar cadenas con subcadenas
# usando list comprehension

# inicializando lista
lista = ['Informática', 'Matemáticas', 'Ingles Avanzado', 'Lengua', 'Alemán Avanzado']

# imprimiendo lista original
print ("La lista original es: " + str(test_list))

# inicializando subcadena
subs = 'Info'


# utilizando
# para obtener una cadena con subcadena
res = [i for i in test_list if subs in i]

# printing result
print ("Todas las cadenas con una subcadena dada son: " + str(res))
```